# What type of fossil is this found at northern Ohio?

Tags: fossils, paleontology

I need some help identifying this fossil.

- I found the rock 30 years ago along the Cuyahoga River in northern Ohio.
  Northern Ohio is glaciated so it is possible that the specimen was transported to Ohio.
- The rock is approx 1.5 x 2.5 inches (3.8 cm x 6.3 cm).
- The rock is calcareous reacting to HCL.
- The rock feels the correct weight for its size.

[image: Front view]
[image: Side view]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course 5 minutes after I post the question, I find the answer myself:
Halysites (Chain Coral) fossil extinct coral from the Silurian period.